# Reorganize array by its date key

Tags: php, arrays, date

How can I reorganize an array by date so that all of the dates will be in order by whichever date came first when I use foreach() ?

Here is my array:

```
$events = array(
"03/06/2016" => array("Random Data 1","Random Data 2"),
"02/15/2016" => array("Random Data 1","Random Data 2"),
"03/07/2016" => array("Random Data 1","Random Data 2")
);
```

Comment: Look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php compare the timestampes from each date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67100201/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort on date's, you should format them as `Y-m-d`. example: 2016-03-06.

Then use the function `ksort()` to sort the array on key values.

```
$events = array(
"2016/03/06" => array("Random Data 1","Random Data 2"),
"2016/02/15" => array("Random Data 1","Random Data 2"),
"2016/03/07" => array("Random Data 1","Random Data 2"),
"2015/04/02" => array("Random Data 1","Random Data 2"),
"2015/05/02" => array("Random Data 1","Random Data 2")
);

var_dump($events);
ksort($events);
var_dump($events);
```

For date formatting see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

For all functions to sort array's see: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like that :

```
//objectify & reverse
foreach($arr as $key=>$var) {
   $arr2[$var]=new DateTime(substr($key,6,4).'-'.substr($key,0,2).'-'.substr($key,3,2));
}

//sort
asort($arr2);

//re-reverse & format
foreach($arr2 as $key=>$var) {
   $var=date_format($var,'m-d-Y');
   $arr3[$var]=$key;
}

//read
foreach($arr3 as $key=>$var) {
   echo $key.': '.$var;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We are going to do this in two steps:

- Reformat the array keys
- Sort the array

#### Let's code!

```
// Define array
$events = array(
    "03/06/2016" => array("Random Data 1","Random Data 2"),
    "02/15/2016" => array("Random Data 1","Random Data 2"),
    "03/07/2016" => array("Random Data 1","Random Data 2")
);

// New array
$sortedEvents = array();

// Change key date format
foreach ($events as $date => $randomDates) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date);
    $sortedEvents[$date->format('Ymd')] = $randomDates;
}

// Sort new array
ksort($sortedEvents);

// Output array
var_dump($sortedEvents);
```

Answer (score -1):

> You need to run **ksort**:

```
$aTmp                  = array();
$aTmp[ '03/06/2016' ] = '2ttt3t23t2t2';
$aTmp[ '02/15/2016' ] = '2ttt3t23t2t2';
$aTmp[ '03/07/2016' ] = '2ttt3t23t2t2';
var_dump( $aTmp );
ksort( $aTmp );
var_dump( $aTmp );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php