# Sorting array with date as key with usort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array whose keys are date which i want to sort in ascending order. I tried sorting it out with ksort() and other sort method which didn't work out. Sorting out with usort() also didn't work.

this is my array

```
array:7 [▼
  "21-07-2017" => array:1 [▶]
  "04-09-2017" => array:3 [▶]
  "27-07-2017" => array:1 [▶]
  "31-07-2017" => array:1 [▶]
  "01-08-2017" => array:2 [▶]
  "05-09-2017" => array:1 [▶]
  "15-09-2017" => array:1 [▶]
]
```

this is what i did.

```
usort($date, function($a, $b) {
          foreach ($a as $value1) {
              foreach ($b as $value2) {
                  return ($value1['date'] < $value2['date']) ? -1 : 1;
              }
          }
        });
```

Are there any in built functions in php which i am missing ?

Comment: ksort should do the trick, can you show what you are expecting the outcome to look like.

Comment: There is already a post concerning how to sort a date array right here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462778/how-to-sort-date-array-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort date array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462778/how-to-sort-date-array-in-php)

Comment: Is ans provided worked for you ?

Comment: ksort can't properly sort your dates because they are in d-m-Y format, but ksort can only treat them as strings, so it will sort on the first number ie the day of the month, not the number of the month. That is why user2486 has the good solution which converts each key into a timestamp, then sorts them.

Answer (score 1):

Convert date to string by `strtotime` function  and then sort by key using `ksort`

```
 $temp = array();
 foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
     $temp[strtotime($key)] = $value;
 }
 ksort($temp);
 $new = array();
 foreach($temp as $key=>$value){
      $new[date("d-m-Y",$key)] = $value;
 }
 print_r($new);
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/862064

Comment: @salathe : I have upated

Comment: instead of creating new arrays, why not just do the timestamp conversion and comparison in the usort function, so that it will maintain the original array the OP is hoping for?

Comment: @i-man : brother I may be wrong, but I think he just tried with `usort` not hard and fast to use only `usort` . Although `usort` is to sort array by value not by key. It would be  wonder  if you provide as you are saying.

Comment: @user2486 I upvoted your answer as I think it should be accepted, and agree with you, but was just thinking maybe the OP will accept it if the original array is sorted

Comment: I used the same array , OP is not given complete array.

Answer (score 0):

Your date values are not formatted in `Y-m-d` -- a format that can be simply sorted naturally as a string value.  When you don't have date/time units ordered from largest to smallest, then you will need to parse the string and convert it into a format that can be compared correctly.

Your date format is already in European format and `strtotime()` will parse that value correctly.  Use `uksort()` to compare values after they have been converted to unix times.  This will sort your array ASC without modifying the original keys.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/S8F4D))

```
$array = [
    "21-07-2017" => ['a'],
    "04-09-2017" => ['b'],
    "27-07-2017" => ['c'],
    "31-07-2017" => ['d'],
    "01-08-2017" => ['e'],
    "05-09-2017" => ['f'],
    "15-09-2017" => ['g'],
];

uksort($array, function($a, $b) { return strtotime($a) <=> strtotime($b);});

var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  '21-07-2017' => 
  array (
    0 => 'a',
  ),
  '27-07-2017' => 
  array (
    0 => 'c',
  ),
  '31-07-2017' => 
  array (
    0 => 'd',
  ),
  '01-08-2017' => 
  array (
    0 => 'e',
  ),
  '04-09-2017' => 
  array (
    0 => 'b',
  ),
  '05-09-2017' => 
  array (
    0 => 'f',
  ),
  '15-09-2017' => 
  array (
    0 => 'g',
  ),
)
```